# BeautifulSoup import error

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a simple, local python script to do some html parsing.  I installed beautifulsoup4 and imported it using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

But I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrape_descriptions.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

I've tried installing BS4 in just about every way.  First I did

```
sudo pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

then I tried downloading the actual files from the website and running

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

and finally I tried

```
sudo su
easy_install BeautifulSoup4
```

All of these operations appear to have completed successfully.  But I'm still getting this error.  I've scoured other posts but pretty much all of them are just installation instructions, which I've already done.

Typing

```
pip freeze
```

shows that bs4 is installed but running

```
$ python3 -i
>>> help('modules')
```

does not appear to list bs4.

Edit 1: Running sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup gives this error:

```
Downloading/unpacking BeautifulSoup
  Downloading BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/BeautifulSoup/setup.py) egg_info for package BeautifulSoup
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/tmp/pip_build_root/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22

    print "Unit tests have failed!"

                                  ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/BeautifulSoup
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/griff/.pip/pip.log
```

Edit 2: Solved! The reason pip3 was failing was because I was using

```
sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup
```

instead of

```
sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
```

which worked.  Thanks!

Comment: If you have both python 2 and 3, and pip installed for both, you might be installing in one and using the other. Check if you have `pip2` or `pip3` commands, and trying running `python2` and doing the import there.

Comment: I do have both pip2 and pip3, but I only have python3, not python2.

Comment: Run `pip3 install BeautifulSoup4`, then.

Comment: Causes an error, listed above.

Comment: Ah. Somehow your pip is weird. You may wish to reinstall pip, by downloading their bootstrap `.py` file and running it with `python3` specifically. After that, `pip3 install BeautifulSoup4` should work. (If it doesn't, it may be a function of weird Python install directories, in which case the answer is system-dependent.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The solution is:

```
sudo pip3 install BeautifulSoup4
```

Comment: great solution @ers81239

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo pip install BeautifulSoup
```

Then

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

You can now call all functions from BeautifulSoup